# SPServices : GetUserProfile with specific param

Tags: web-services, spservices

I want to use the SPService GetUserProfile, but I don't have the accountName, the GUID, the Index or the email... I only have a param which is **employeeNumber** (I guess this is specific to my compagnie).

I check on : http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UserProfileService, but I can't find how to do it.

Is it possible to get a user profile searching with a specific param ?

Answer (score 1):

use some LDAP code to search for a usable field (if the UID in the document exists in some field in AD) Replace FIELD with your equivalent field. Replace DOMAIN with your domain like LDAP://example.corp:

```
string sFilter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(FIELD={0}))", query);
string adPath = "LDAP://DOMAIN";

using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(adPath))
{
    //these are the attributes that will show      
    string[] attribs = new string[] { "samAccountName" };

    // Search using these filters
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de, sFilter, attribs);

    using (SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll())
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < src.Count)
        {
            SearchResult sr = src[i];
            user = new UserInfo();
            foreach (string key in attribs)
            {
                if (sr.Properties.Contains(key))
                {
                    foreach (object o in sr.Properties[key])
                    {
                        if (key == "samAccountName")
                        {
                            user.imageUrl ="https://my.slalom.com/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/2d_" + (string)o + "_MThumb.jpg";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/6c3e7730-f204-447d-82b6-2b4538657f02/getuserprofile-by-one-of-the-attribute-employee-id?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I don't have access to the server, I can only use HTML/JS to access the webservices. I currently use SPServices to connect to the webservice, and it works great, but I don't know how to get a profile having only the employeeNumber

Comment: i dont think you can get it but employee number...did you try to index?

Comment: I tried using the index but it didn't work, the index is not even return when I get current user. Maybe it is not possible using only SPServices... Too bad.